# Win 32 API - Set window top most and not clickable

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm trying to set a chrome window top most and not clickable, I tried:

```
IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
SetWindowPos(chrome, HWND_TOPMOST , 0, 0, 0, 0,  SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000
SetWindowLong(chrome, GWL_EXSTYLE, initialStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
```

That makes the window top most but now you can click through the window.

What do I have to change to make the window to capture and ignore mouse click and key stroke events?

Comment: Remove `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`. Note that it cannot capture key stroke events though because it cannot become the foreground window due to `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`, and if it could then it would only capture keystrokes while it's in focus. Please describe your use case a bit better, it seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: If this can be done. There is a case that a new opened application window overlapped by the chrome window totally, then this new window can't be clickable and moved by mouse, it can't be operated on. This will confuse users. So could you share why you want to achieve this?